# c# asp.net making a session equal to a columns data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, session

I have a problem i can't get my session to be equal to my database column User.Roles. I want to be able to make, so the users can't use my admin system. If you have an idea please share it with me.

```
if (Session["Rolle"] != null)
{
    Admin_panel.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: is it a spelling mistake?
`Session["Rolle"] != null`

Comment: no, my problem is that i have no idea how to write it so it can be == my colemns data, if u have an idea please share. The colemn is under User.Roles "rolle" is just a name i gave it

Comment: show some more code in order to being helped.

Comment: I cant understand what you want!

Comment: i got this table in the sql database 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Admin] (
    [Id]         INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Brugernavn] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Kodeord]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Rolle]      INT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

i want to use the rolle's data to be stored in my session so if that user enters a site and the session is not null he will be able to see the admin panel on the sites

Comment: So when the user logs in, you are putting all the data from the user row from this table into session variables?  Since Rolle is not null, it will always be filled. Is there a specific Rolle that is equal to an admin type?  I.E. 355 = admin, so you would change your code to look to see if session["Rolle"] == "355" etc.